# Show div based on php if statements on a number of Select boxes

Tags: javascript, php, html

This question has been partly answered in other threads, but I can't figure out the complete code. Basically I have 5 from Select boxes and a user picks and answers from each box then after they finish I want to show a div based on the answers - either automatically shows or need to press a button to show.

Eg :

```
If option1 = ans1, option2 = ans1, option3= ans1, option4 = ans1, option5 = ans1 
then show div1 

Else if  option1 = **ans2**, option2 = ans1, option3= ans1, option4 = ans1, option5 =     ans1 then
show div2

Else if  option1 = **ans2**, option2 = **ans2**, option3= ans1, option4 = ans1, option5 = ans1 then
show div3

Else if  option1 = **ans2**, option2 = **ans2**, option3= **ans2**, option4 = ans1, option5 = ans1 then
show div3
```

.... so on

```
Else if  option1 = **ans3**, option2 = **ans3**, option3= **ans3**, option4 = **ans3**, option5 = **ans3** then
show div3
```

Anyone have any ideas on the exact way this would be done?

Thanks so much

Brent

Comment: Did you try to program it?

Comment: Do you have some code ? paste it to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `jQuery` to do this on the client side, without need to refresh the page.

All you need is to define your conditions inside an array of objects:

```
conditions = [
    {
        div: '#div1', // div id
        conditions: { // you can have any combination of options
            option1: 'answer1',
            option2: 'answer2'
        }
    },
    {
        div: '#div2',
        conditions: {
            option1: 'answer1',
            option2: 'answer3',
            option3: 'answer2'
        }
    }
];
```

This is a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLeDr

Comment: This example is perfectly what I am after hutchbat! Thanks so much.

Comment: Sp for some reason this isn't working for me. Can I possibly show you my code somewhere and see if you know how I broke the fine work you did. Basically once all the select boxes are filled out all the content in the main content div is given the class hide...

Comment: @user3762340 sure ! why not ? my example will work when the conditions are met.

Comment: Yeah I can see it works perfectly - it is going to be me - for some reason once the selection boxes are completely the correct div displays, but all out content within the main content dive is given the has class="hide" added to it. What do you need from me.

Comment: Do you mind if I email the code to your business email - this comment area has a 550 character limit

Comment: Thanks - that was easier. It is on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jx5bh/

That code doesn't include the separate header and footer files.

Comment: 1. You've not included `jQuery` in jsfiddle. 2. Your HTML is not valid. 3. You've forgot to define `.hide` in CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/kXwFJ/1/

Comment: Ok - in the header I have the following which should cover 1. and 3. right??

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Bootstrap Framework -->

Comment: Was missing a div around the answers, thus the class hide was being applied to the content of the main div. Again, thanks. Your code is perfect!

Comment: Hutchbat can I ask 1 more thing of you. In the js is how can I make it  show a div if there are no results based on there answers. Eg ans1,ans2,ans2,ans4,ans1 are selected which shows div1, but then the user changes to ans1,ans1,ans1,ans1,ans1 which has no div assigned to it, I want hide the past div and show a common div to show that says 'no result'. Is that possible

Comment: `if(valid===1){ // ... }else{ // show no results }`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, when a user pick one of the checkbox the appropriate div is displayed?

In PHP you have to change page : when the user picks a box, he has to submit the form and you can show the appropriate div with:

```
echo '<div> ... </div>'
```

In Javascript your user won't have to submit any form.
First put div1, div2 etc with display: none.
Handle onChange events on your boxes. And within your event change the 'display' css selector of the appropriate div to 'box" or 'inline' or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

with those commas, what do you mean? logical "and"?
if so:

```
    <?php

    $answer = array(
       1 => "answer1",
       2 => "answer2"
    );
    $options = $_GET['options'];
    switch ($options) {
       case array($answer1,$answer1,$answer1,$answer1):
          echo "<div>div1</div>";
       break;
       case array($answer2,$answer1,$answer1,$answer1):
          echo "<div>div2</div>";
       break;
       case array($answer2,$answer2,$answer1,$answer1):
          echo "<div>div3</div>";
       break;
       case array($answer2,$answer2,$answer2,$answer1):
          echo "<div>div4</div>";
       break;
    }
?>
<form method="post">
   <select name="options[]">
      <option>answer1</option>
      <option>answer2</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="options[]">
      <option>answer1</option>
      <option>answer2</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="options[]">
      <option>answer1</option>
      <option>answer2</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="options[]">
      <option>answer1</option>
      <option>answer2</option>
   </select>
   <br />
</form>
```

now, time to ask: is this your homework? Better not do this next time if so ;)

Comment: Thanks for helping. Like the idea, but can't get this to work.